# Google Backup and Sync won't "Ask before removing both copies"?

Tags: sync, google-drive, google-backup-and-sync

The Google Drive Help Center [explains](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987?visit_id=637295177456920743-2520951027&p=sync_deleted_items&hl=en&rd=2) that when you delete a file from your computer you have these three options:

1. **Always remove both copies**: When you delete something on your computer or drive.google.com, it will be deleted everywhere.
2. **Never remove both copies**: When you delete something on your computer, it will stay on drive.google.com
3. **Ask before removing both copies**: When you delete something on your computer, it will ask if you want to delete it everywhere.

And I'm interested in the third option, but in my case it doesn't work the way it's described above. In fact, it works exactly as #1, i.e. a file gets deleted everywhere without any prompt. Why could that be?